# Saving a matrix into a file (row by row) in Python

Tags: python, file, matrix, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to create a large matrix (2x1000000) and save each row in a file.

I've tried working with a small matrix and it works fine:

```
yy=str(np.eye((5), dtype='int')).split("\n")
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(5):
        f.write(yy[i][2:11])
        f.write("\n")
```

Now, when I try to generalize, I face two problems.

when I cast with 'str', it ends up placing the newline char in the middle of the lines... For example:

```
T=str(np.zeros((2,60+1), dtype='int'))
```

Creates the following:

> ```
> '[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]\n [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]'
> ```

In addition, When I go very large and try to save a row in to a file, 
It saves it with the three dots in the middle... something like this:

> ```
> "0 0 1... 0 0 0"
> ```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use something line [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) ?

Comment: why to you convert to `str`? why not just `write` the numpy array?

Comment: Thomas,
numpy.savetxt won't let me save row by row... In my real code, I do operations between saving one row and the other... 'savetxt' overwrites the previous line... so I end up having only the last row saved in the file.

Comment: Shai,
I get the error "write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray" if  I remove the 'str'